# Add an additional component as soon as user types on input

Tags: reactjs, components

I know how to add an item based on state. When user type something on input, It generates list items based on state(mapping) like below code.

```js
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input name="name" value={name} onChange={handleInput} />
      <button onClick={() => handleBtn(names)}>Click Me</button>
      {names.map((item) => (
        <div>{item}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

But I want to add one more additional component automatically as soon as user type something on input.
To add an additional component  easily right after finish typing like below image (**+ List Item**)
[Here is an example](https://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/keep-indent-list.png)

**(Additional question)**
I write a function which adding a listItem component onChange event. But it adds a component every time user type text as you know.. So I guess, To add an additional component successfully, I need to know when user starts and finishes typing not to add it multiple times(like user stops for a wile and typing again). Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could use onBlur so when the user finishes typing and loses the focus from the input you could add the additional component.

onBlur will be called every time the field loses the focus so if you want to add the additional component only if the value of the input has been changed, then you need to check if the value was changed after the blur, and then add the new component.

Comment: Thank you! I missed to check the value of input has been changed. And additionally,  I guess I can use ```reduce()``` for adding an additional component.